# Node.js empty request body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to node.js and trapped by passing data from client end to server. Here is the code on the client:

```
var roomName = document.indexform.room[1].value;
const roomInfo = { value: `${roomName}`, text: `${roomName}` };
console.log(roomInfo);
const options = {
  method: "POST",
  header: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(roomInfo),
};
fetch("/index", options);
```

Code in server:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json({ limit: "1mb" }));
app.post("/index", (request, response) => {
  console.log(request.body);
});
```

The output of request.body is always `{}`. I really don't know why.

Comment: don't stringify your body at the client if you're sending JSON bodies.

Comment: Thanks, i tried this but still get empty

Answer (score 2):

[fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options) `options` just acceps `headers` (not `header`) setting to set the request headers.

Let's correct your attribute name:

```
var roomName = document.indexform.room[1].value;
const roomInfo = { value: `${roomName}`, text: `${roomName}` };
console.log(roomInfo);
const options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { // not "header"
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(roomInfo),
};
fetch("/index", options);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Looks like i waste whole day on a simple s lol.